# How do you get Azure Logic app to send an email

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I used this tutorial to create a logic app that sends an email through my gmail account to my work account whenever a resource changes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app

However, for some reason, whenever I change anything on virtual machine, for example stopping/starting it, nothing happens. When I try to run the trigger manually, it fails with the message:

Failed to start a run of logic app newLogicApp. There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments.

All of my resources are in the same resource group under the same subscription.

The resource group doesn't have any app service plan in it. I don't know if this is required and if it is, how do you link that app service plan to the logic app itself.

Here's a code view of the logic app:

```
{
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azureeventgrid": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/7137186b-8ebc-4bc6-952f-55efcb96d2f5/resourceGroups/testRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureeventgrid-2",
                "connectionName": "azureeventgrid-2",
                "id": "/subscriptions/7137186b-8ebc-4bc6-952f-55efcb96d2f5/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureeventgrid"
            },
            "gmail_1": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/7137186b-8ebc-4bc6-952f-55efcb96d2f5/resourceGroups/testRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/gmail-1",
                "connectionName": "gmail-1",
                "id": "/subscriptions/7137186b-8ebc-4bc6-952f-55efcb96d2f5/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/gmail"
            }
        }
    },
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {
                    "Send_email": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "Body": "Resource: @{triggerBody()?['topic']}\n\nEvent Type: @{triggerBody()?['eventType']}\n\nEvent ID: @{triggerBody()?['id']}\n\nTime: @{triggerBody()?['eventTime']}",
                                "Subject": "Resource updated: @{triggerBody()?['subject']}",
                                "To": "xxx@yyy.com"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['gmail_1']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/Mail"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@triggerBody()?['data']['operationName']",
                                "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "If"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_resource_event_occurs": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "properties": {
                            "destination": {
                                "endpointType": "webhook",
                                "properties": {
                                    "endpointUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                                }
                            },
                            "topic": "/subscriptions/7137186b-8ebc-4bc6-952f-55efcb96d2f5/resourceGroups/testRG"
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureeventgrid']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('7137186b-8ebc-4bc6-952f-55efcb96d2f5')}/providers/@{encodeURIComponent('Microsoft.Resources.ResourceGroups')}/resource/eventSubscriptions",
                    "queries": {
                        "x-ms-api-version": "2017-09-15-preview"
                    }
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, this tutorial just helps us how to monitor virtual machine changes but can't monitor start/stop of the VM. I test it on my Azure portal, if start/stop the VM, the logic app will not be triggered. But when I resize the VM, the logic was triggered successfully. You can test again it by yourself.

By the way, if you want to be notified when the VM start, you can use another solution. Go to your VM and click "Alerts" --> "New alert rule". Then you can add a "Start Virtual Machine" condition(another condition which may helps you is "Create or Update Virtual Machine"), and create action group to send an email to yourself.(shown as below screenshot)

[image]

**Update:**

It seems(from your view code) you haven't add "Event Type Item" in the trigger(When a resource event occurs) in your logic app, the tutorial you shared mentioned it, you can look through it again or refer to the screenshot I post below.

[image]

[image]

**Update2:**

[image]

[image]

Here is the code of logic app:

```
{
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azureeventgrid": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/*********/resourceGroups/hurylogicVM/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureeventgrid",
                "connectionName": "azureeventgrid",
                "id": "/subscriptions/*********/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastasia/managedApis/azureeventgrid"
            },
            "office365": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/*********/resourceGroups/hurylogicVM/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                "connectionName": "office365",
                "id": "/subscriptions/*********/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastasia/managedApis/office365"
            }
        }
    },
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "If_a_virtual_machine_in_your_resource_group_has_changed": {
                "actions": {
                    "Send_email_when_virtual_machine_updated": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "Body": "Resource: @{triggerBody()?['topic']}\nEvent type: @{triggerBody()?['eventType']}\nEvent id: @{triggerBody()?['id']}\nEvent time: @{triggerBody()?['eventTime']}",
                                "Subject": "Resource updated:@{triggerBody()?['subject']}",
                                "To": "v-shuhsh@microsoft.com"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/Mail"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@triggerBody()?['data']['operationName']",
                                "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "If"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_resource_event_occurs": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "properties": {
                            "destination": {
                                "endpointType": "webhook",
                                "properties": {
                                    "endpointUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                                }
                            },
                            "filter": {
                                "includedEventTypes": [
                                    "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceActionSuccess",
                                    "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceDeleteSuccess",
                                    "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess"
                                ]
                            },
                            "topic": "/subscriptions/*********/resourceGroups/hurylogicVM"
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureeventgrid']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('*********')}/providers/@{encodeURIComponent('Microsoft.Resources.ResourceGroups')}/resource/eventSubscriptions",
                    "queries": {
                        "x-ms-api-version": "2017-09-15-preview"
                    }
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The screenshot of my resoure group:

[image]

Comment: That didn't work. I tried resizing the VM and that was successful but the logic app was still not triggered.

Comment: Hi @tt1997, it seems you haven't added "Event Type Item" in the trigger(When a resource event occurs), I have updated my answer. If it still doesn't work, could you please share the error message or check your logic app by click "Overview" --> under "Runs history", check if it was be triggered and how it run. And share the screenshot in your question.

Comment: Hi @tt1997, according to your "Run history", it seems your logic hasn't been triggered. But I can't find any mistake in your screenshot, so I update my answer(under "update2") and post the screenshot of my logic app and the code. I followed the steps in the tutorial you shared and works fine. Hope it would be helpful to you.

Comment: Hi @tt1997, may I know if your problem has been solved ?

Comment: seems like it's still not working. I will try and put the logic app in a resource group that contains an app service plan to make sure. Can you list down the steps of what you did and share a picture of your resource group as well?

Comment: Yep still not working. I tried putting it in the same app service plan too

Comment: Hi @tt1997, I have uploaded the screenshot of my resource group in the answer above. The steps I've taken are all in the tutorial you provided, could you please share the screenshot of your logic app(the screenshot of your logic app designer view, not the code view), I want to look through the details of your logic app and try to find the issue in it.

Comment: here you go                                                                              https://imgur.com/7O67e6t                                                                 https://imgur.com/ehyUtBC

Comment: Hi @tt1997, it seems your logic app is exactly same as mine except the email. I send email by o365 and your email is gmail. But the screenshot you shared before shows us nothing in "Run history", so the logic wasn't triggered once. The problem is more likely to be in the trigger but not the email. So I think this issue belongs to troubleshooting, you can raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request and ask the microsoft support team for help. They can see your background data.

Comment: Seems like I'll have to upgrade to a paid subscription to be able to ask for help. I'm a student so I was just hoping to get a solution. I'll see if I can figure it out by posting on perhaps the MSDN forums... Don't really wanna pay for the service haha

Comment: @tt1997 Ok, understand. Could you please remove your logic app and create it again, just follow the steps in the tutorial you provided. Maybe there is something wrong in your creatation or something wrong with the system.

Comment: I've tried that multiple times but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

May you visit the following article that guides step by step
https://sps-cloud-architect.blogspot.com/2019/12/azure-logic-apps-send-email-using-send.html